# SSRS dataset with multiple sentence list

Tags: reporting-services, expression

i have a SSRS dataset field called DESCRIPTION which has sentence for multiple lines. for example, if my id is 100, it has following data in description field:

- description1
- description2
- description3
  so, i want to list them on my SSRS report with same horizontal allignment.

I tried using SPLIT function but didnot help.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a table. Set it to be grouped by ID. In the details row set the textbox to have an expression like this:

```
=Fields!DESCRIPTION.Value + " for id " + CStr(Fields!ID.Value)
```

This will repeat for each description in the dataset. Remove the top and bottom border on this textbox so the results appear to be in one box.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. Sorry i was trying to explain my problem so explanation of question was mistake. so i edited the question. Actually i want only the descriptions field. for which i used =Fields!DESCRIPTION.Value , but it doesn't list all the rows, it gives only description1, but i want it to list all the fields i.e. description1, description2, description3

Comment: @axlrose89 Is the number of columns always the same? Are the descriptions in separate columns in the database? A better solution is usually to change your query so that the descriptions are in rows of one column, not pivoted out like this.